# Async Function: Which Console.log Is called first?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

My question is in reference to the code below. When I call this file on my terminal "node app.js"...I'm expecting to see **[B]** first before **[A]** since the function **addAddress(res)** is Async and it has the keyword **await** so it should be completed first before moving on/is called before the **console.log("[A]")**. Also, my understanding was that the Last item in a CallStack is also the first item to be called/executed Out (LASTinFirtsOut). So since the function **addAddress(res)** was last called it should be executed before continuing.

Thank you all once again looking forward to furthering my understanding.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/relationshipDemo', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("OH NO MONGO CONNECTION ERROR!!!!")
        console.log(err)
    })


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first: String,
    last: String,
    addresses: [
        {
            _id: { id: false },
            street: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            country: String
        }
    ]
})


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const makeUser = async () => {
    const u = new User({
        first: 'Harry',
        last: 'Potter',
    })
    u.addresses.push({
        street: '123 Sesame St.',
        city: "New York",
        state: 'NY',
        country: 'USA'
    })
    const res = await u.save()
    addAddress(res)
    console.log(res);
    console.log("[A]")
}



const addAddress = async (id) => {
    const userNow = await User.findById(id);
    userNow.addresses.push({
        street: '123 Florida',
        city: "Miami",
        state: 'FL',
        country: 'USA'
    })
    const userSaved = await userNow.save();
    console.log(userSaved)
    console.log('[B]')
}

makeUser()
```

Comment: If I expected to see [B] before [A] I would also expect that the thing that displays [A] will have __awaited__ the thing that displays [B] before displaying [A].  In your case, that would be accomplished by calling `await addAddress(res)` instead of just `addAddress(res)`.

Comment: "*the function addAddress(res) is Async and it has the keyword await so it should be completed first before moving on* - the `async`/`await` only means that the code **inside** the `async` function will wait before moving on. The call `addAddress(res)` still just returns a promise immediately, and must be `await`ed if you want the rest of the code in `makeUser` to wait before moving on.

Comment: @Wyck I figured it out after giving it some thoughts. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RND809 sounds like you have the basic idea.  Think of it like this.  If I said "1) Order a pizza.  2) Shout 'hooray!'".  You would shout 'hooray!' before the pizza actually arrived because I only told you to *order* the pizza.  You'd follow step #2 after ordering but before the pizza arrived.  If I wanted you to shout **after** the pizza arrived, I'd have to say it differently, like "order a pizza and **wait** for it to arrive, then shout 'hooray!'"  That's what `await` does.

Comment: @Wyck Exactly that made sense haha I re did my code and it worked smoothly.

I had the wrong assumption. I thought that since it was an Async function calling another Async function that it would automatically have the Await implicitly, but that's not the cases, so we do have to use await keyword if I want that result.